# Influence of The Protagonist's Birthday

Tags: character-development, plot

I was writing up my story and i wanted to know how much should the Protagonist's Birthday be part of the story. I have seen many stories in books,movies and games in where birthdays play very important part in the story examples include Harry Potter etc. I want to know how much should the Protagonist's Birthday play a part in the story if it needs to be included

Comment: How much should any event be part of a story? A birthday, or missing one, is only as important as it needs to be for the plot.

Comment: This question is very vague, a discussion-starter rather than an answerable question. Is there some reason you think a birthday should be a part of *your* story?

Comment: I'm not sure of why this was closed as opinion based. It can be answered objectively. Voting for reopening.

Comment: And here's where I wish I had mod powers...so I could have removed the dead tag without bumping the question.   I voted to keep it firmly closed.  Like Aunt Petunia's heart.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is about the plot. Harry Potter's a little special in that his birthday signaled a new year at Hogwart's.

Mostly birthdays play pivotal roles because they're a time for reflection on someone's life.

Comment: "Everything is about the plot." Well, except when everything is about the character.

Comment: @KenMohnkern, yes, but what good is your character without a plot. Of course, what good is a plot without a character. OK, your story needs both.

Answer (score 2):

It should be emphasized to the extent that the fact of the character getting older is significant to the story you want to tell.